# Beamer inline itemize and enumeration

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate, itemize

My goal is to produce inline lists (`itemize` and `enumerate`) in combination with the `beamer` document class. The symbols of these lists should use the same symbols as their non-inline counterparts to match the look of the `beamer` template.

For standard document classes, this can be achieved by packages such as [shortlst](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/shortlst). However, I use `shortlst` in combination with `beamer`, no list symbols show up.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{shortlst}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  % standard enumerate where item symbol style is set by beamer template 
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item this
    \item takes
    \item too
    \item much
    \item space
  \end{enumerate}

  % my goal is to have an inline list which uses the same symbols as the "standard" lists
  % in this example, no list symbols appear at all
  \begin{shortenumerate}
    \item this
    \item one
    \item doesn't
  \end{shortenumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hi is this appropriate?

```
\documentclass[slidestop]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}


\newcommand{\inlineitem}{%
\leavevmode\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}
}
\newcounter{newenumi}
\setcounter{newenumi}{1}

\newcommand{\inlineenum}{%
 {%
 \setcounter{enumi}{\thenewenumi}%
 \leavevmode\usebeamertemplate{enumerate  item}
 \stepcounter{newenumi}
 \setcounter{enumi}{0}
 }
}

\newcommand{\resetinlineenum}{
 \setcounter{newenumi}{1}
}


\begin{frame}{Test}
 \inlineitem short \inlineitem list test
 \inlineenum test \inlineenum test \resetinlineenum \inlineenum new test
  \begin{block}{in a block} 
  \inlineitem short in a block
 \end{block}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item normal
  \item 
 \end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Three new user-commands here: `\inlineitem` produces just a ball.  `\inlineenum`a inline enumerate label and `\resetinlineenum` resets it at your will.

[image]

### For environmentalists:

```
\documentclass[slidestop]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\newenvironment{inlineitemize}{%
 \let\par\relax%
 \def\item{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}\hspace{1mm}}
 \leavevmode%
}{}

\newenvironment{inlineenumerate}{%
 \let\par\relax%
 \setcounter{enumi}{1}%
 \def\item{\usebeamertemplate{enumerate  item} \stepcounter{enumi}}%
 \leavevmode%
}{%
 \setcounter{enumi}{0}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{inlineitemize}
\item item
\item 2


\end{inlineitemize}%
\begin{inlineenumerate}
 \item test 

 \item test 

 \item test

\end{inlineenumerate}

  \begin{block}{in a block} 
\begin{inlineenumerate}
 \item test 

 \item test 

 \item test

\end{inlineenumerate}
 \end{block}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item normal
  \item 
 \end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you - not a perfect (_i.e._ built-in or package-based) solution, but it works. It seems there is no way to achieve this via existing packages. Just curious: is there a nice way to encapsulate above solution into new environments, say `itemizebeamerinline` and `enumeratebeamerinline`?

Comment: If you want it perfect, you need to specify your needs. Basically everything can be achieved.

Comment: Well, your "environmentalist" solution comes pretty close - thank you very much.

Comment: @bloodworks, When I use the theme Berlin, the square bullets are in black, while they should be in blue. For the theme Madrid, I get the same result as you have showed above. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Excellent. To tweak the inline enumerate style, e.g. to add brackets around the numbers, I added the following line immediately before ``\def`` inside the ``inlineenumerate`` environment: ``\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{(\insertenumlabel)~}``

Comment: To prevent the enumi counters interfering with each other in cases where an inline enumerate environment is nested inside a standard enumerate, the following may help: https://pastebin.com/YkjVYFUf

Comment: How can the environmental solution be altered to change the marker's colour, and to continue enumeration from previous items?

Comment: Is there a way to increase the distance between the items of `inlineenumerate` items, without manually putting `hspace{0.5cm}` in the individual items?

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry to post an answer, but since I haven't reached 50 points yet I can't comment it seems. You can fix the color issue with this:

```
\newcommand{\inlineitem}{\leavevmode{\color{blue}\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}} }
```

Probably very crude but it does work for Madrid.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't be afraid to add answers!