# The itemize bullet symbol of beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm using the command `$\bullet$` in beamer, but I would like to use the 3d bullet symbol like that the itemize bullet. Anybody?
I'm using

```
\documentclass[notes=show,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow} % theme
\beamertemplateshadingbackground{red!15}{blue!15}
%\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\begin{itemize}
\item XXX
\item YYY
\end{itemize}

{\color{blue}$\bullet$} XXX
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like so:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\newcommand\mytextbullet{\leavevmode%
\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}\hspace{.5em}}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\begin{itemize}
\item XXX
\item YYY
\end{itemize}

\mytextbullet XXX \mytextbullet XXX \mytextbullet XXX
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Simply using the template.

See also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94478/beamer-inline-itemize-and-enumeration/94521#94521).