# Enumerate label numbers

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I have an enumerate list in this MWE.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First one
\item Second one
\item Third one
\end{enumerate}
In the above list, 2 and 3 are what more important.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want "2" and "3" in the text to be the same as in the list, a blue solid circle with white numbers.

How do I do that? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94478/beamer-inline-itemize-and-enumeration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the appearance is the only thing matters, then the following will do:

## Code

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\mynum[1]{%
  \usebeamercolor{enumerate item}%
  \tikzset{beameritem/.style={circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=2ex,text=enumerate item.bg,fill=enumerate item.fg,font=\footnotesize}}%
  \tikz[baseline=(n.base)]\node(n)[beameritem]{#1};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First one
\item Second one
\item Third one
\end{enumerate}
In the above list, \mynum{2} and \mynum{3} are what more important.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This is almost the same answer, but with safe reference to  label names instead of item numbers (i.e., when the item order is changed, the references are still correct).

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\itemref[1]{%
\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
\node[circle, fill=enumerate item.fg, inner sep=.6pt] (char) {\scriptsize\color{white}\ref{#1}};}}

\begin{document}

(Compile twice to solve the cross references).  

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{one} First one
\item \label{two} Second one
\item  Last minuted included item without importance 
\item \label{three} Third one
\end{enumerate}
In the above list, \itemref{one}, \itemref{two} and \itemref{three} are the more important.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have an error with your code: Undefined color `enumerate item.fg'

Comment: @Antonin Still work fine in my computer with the vanilla TexLive 2013...may be you are using an outdated version?

Answer (score 8):

For sake of completeness, I believe the best solution is the combination of @Markus and @Fran. References to item labels with templated markers:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\itemref[1]{{\renewcommand{\insertenumlabel}{\ref{#1}}%
  \usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}}}

\begin{document}

(Compile twice to solve the cross references).  

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{one} First one
\item \label{two} Second one
\item  Last minuted included item without importance 
\item \label{three} Third one
\end{enumerate}
In the above list, \itemref{one}, \itemref{two} and \itemref{three} are the more important.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Render of latex with enumerate references]

Answer (score 5):

Beamer draws the enumerate item numbers using the template "enumerate item", which gets the item number from \insertenumlabel. So just temporarily redefine the \insertenumlabel macro to show the \ref{...} value you need and then use the same template, using \usebeamertemplate:

```
\newcommand\mynum[1]{{\renewcommand{\insertenumlabel}{#1}%
      \usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}}}
```

This should work independent of what enumerate item template your inner theme you has chosen.

Answer (score 1):

With this code:

```
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,fill=blue] (char) {#1};}}

\circled{\color{white} 3}
```

you get this:

[image: The picture shows "In your text, 2 and 3" where 2 and 3 are circled.]