# Citing an enumerated item in text with beamer bullet

Tags: beamer

I am using latex beamer and would like to refer to an item in an enumerated list. In the list, the item is numbered within a bullet but when I refer to it later in the text, it comes without a bullet, in the default style. Is there a way I can write the number within the bullet?

Thanks and sorry if this question is repeated.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152710/11604) help?

Comment: Perfect, Fran. Thank you very much. 

Yes, Bobyandbob, I will do it from the next time. Thank you for the welcome wishes!