# The paralist package does not work properly in Beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, paralist

I'm trying to create a simple inline list within [Beamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_%28LaTeX%29), and the environment paralist is not behaving as expected:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage{paralist} % inline list

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{inparaenum}[-]
    \item item1 \item item2 \item item3
  \end{inparaenum}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Instead of having those items inline, this what I see as the result:

[image]

Comment: You should not use `paralist` with `beamer` as it redefines the list-styles from `beamer`. You can find a work around here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94478

Comment: I found that post. It does work but the problem is that the symbol used is not the same as the one I have in the rest of the document. I use the triangle and it shows blue, but when I use the approach on that post it shows a black triangle and the size of text for some reason is reduced.

Comment: You should extend your MWE a bit. Do you really want - for this itemization or do you want to get those triangles? You have to be a bit more precise in order to prevent volunteers from spending time in "wrong" answers as Bernard just kindly did. Thanks.

Comment: Well usually people ask to bring a minimum working example that shows the problem, so that's what I did. I can't paste the entire Beamer presentation here, can I? I would like to use an inline list that shows the same symbol as the one that's defined for my presentation, that's all.

Comment: Yes, but what is your symbol? Seems like `Madrid` works, what style do you use? (ok, I just see that the blue triangle is the default. I do not use `beamer`... I will have a look now.)

Comment: I use it like this: `\usetheme{default}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=tudCyan}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=tudGreen}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=tudGreen}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=tudOrange}`, where those colors are defined as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

beamer has its own list definitions and loading package like enumitem or paralist can destroy them. It is better to define your own commands, e.g. something like this:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, fleqn]{beamer}

\newcommand\paraitem{%
 \quad
 \makebox[\labelwidth][r]{%
 \makelabel{%
 \usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}}\hskip\labelsep}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1 \paraitem item 2 \paraitem item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution seems to work but it has too much space between the items. I removed the `\quad` and that reduced the space, but it still has too much space between items. Is there a way to reduce that space?

Comment: You can use `0.5\labelwidth` in the makebox argument.

Answer (score 3):

The `shortlst` package seems to be compatible with beamer. It deines a `runenumerate` and a `runitemize` environments. To redefine the item marker as in beamer, I had to load `etoolbox` and patch the `item` command on entering  the environment.

*Note:* As`shortlst` is not part of TeX Live, nor MiKTeX (for licensing reasons, as far as I know), you will have to install it by yourself in your Local TeXMF tree.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, fleqn]{beamer}
\definecolor{tudCyan}{RGB}{0,144,207} \definecolor{tudGreen}{RGB}{39,131,142} \definecolor{tudOrange}{RGB}{216,130,62}
\usetheme{default} \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=tudCyan} \setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=tudGreen} \setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=tudGreen} \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=tudOrange}


\usepackage{shortlst}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{runitemize}{\apptocmd{\item}{$\color{tudCyan}\scriptstyle\blacktriangleright $\hskip\labelsep}{}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \begin{itemize}%[label = \textendash, itemjoin=\quad]
    \item item1 \item item2 \item item3
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{runitemize}%[label = \textendash, itemjoin=\quad]
    \item item1 \item item2 \item item3
  \end{runitemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work as it removes ALL symbols from itemize environments that I use in other slides.

Comment: If you explain the details I can see how to arrange this. Note it should normally be active only on this particular environment.

Comment: Neither `paralist` nor `enumitem` are compatible with `beamer`

Comment: I use the default theme but I have changed the colors as follows: `\usetheme{default}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=tudCyan}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=tudGreen}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=tudGreen}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=tudOrange}`

Comment: @egreg I think we have to mention in the other way around to do justice to these packages as  `beamer` is not compatible with many packages (with valid reasons of course).

Comment: @aaragon: I'm sorry, your changing colours code  doesn't work as is (‘unknown color’ is the error message), so I can'r see what happens.

Comment: @Bernard in making a MWE I removed those as well. These are the definitions: `\definecolor{tudCyan}{RGB}{0,144,207}
\definecolor{tudGreen}{RGB}{39,131,142}
\definecolor{tudOrange}{RGB}{216,130,62}
`

Comment: If I understand well, you would like to have the same blue triangle as itemize marker, but for an in-line list?

Comment: @Bernard that's correct.

Comment: @egreg: `shortlst` seems to work (see my modified answer). Are you aware of any incompatibilities?

Comment: @aaragon: See my new solution with `shortlst`.

Comment: @Bernard I never heard about `shortlst`.

Comment: I've been using  it for years for lists arranged in columns, but horizontally numbered (like what tasks does now). It is not in  TeX Live nor MiKTeX for licensing reasons, but can be found on CTAN. What's interesting here is it has a ‘runitemize/enumerate’ environment that sems to work within Beamer context.

Comment: I see, but I don't think it's reasonable to mark your answer as the correct one as people would have to install the `shortlist` package themselves. It seems to be a lot of trouble for something that seems quite simple IMHO.